# Avoid Windows Login Prompt While Accessing SQL Report Server 2016

Tags: credentials, ssrs-2016

Could u please help me on how to stop prompting the credential while opening report manager/ report server  in SSRS 2016.

I searched lot in google but no success.

Kindly help me.

Thilan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the report server is on your local intranet, try accessing it without using the FQDN - that's what solved it for me.

eg. instead of http://server.localdomain.com/reports, use http://server/reports.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to Tools and click on Internet Options
3. Under the Security tab, click on Trusted sites and click the Sites button and Add Report Manager/Report Server URL to the trusted sites.
4. Then click Custom Level, and check the option Automatic logon with current user name and password
5. Repeat #3 and #4 for Local Intranet

Comment: Actually credential prompt not anything with IE or any other browser. Basically it is get prompt from SQL Report Server 2016. I need to know how to setup SQL Report server setup not to prompt that credential.